# EF Core 2 databse first - mapping custom functions

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-2.0, custom-function

I am using EF Core 2.0 with database first with SQL Server 2017, it's working fine for my tables and views. However, I have a problem to map the existing functions I do have in my database.

Function: (example)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [DBO].[GETDATETIME]()
RETURNS DateTime
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT GETDATE())
END
```

SQL query:

```
SELECT GETDATETIME()
```

PROBLEM:

I would like to call my function in the same way (or similar) we do in the SQL query.

I found the following way in some examples:

1 - Create the static method in my XDbContext class:

```
[DbFunction("dbo.GetDateTime")]
public static DateTime GetDateTime()
{
     throw new Exception();
}
```

2 - Call your function within a relation with another table:

```
from t in _dbContext.Customer 
select new { period = XDbContext.GetDateTime() };
```

But I need to do that using the function in a independent way, as we can do it in a SQL query.

I would really appreciate any help or useful tip.

Comment: Can you explain _I need to do that using the function in a independent way, as we can do on SQL Query_

Comment: I want to call the function, only. Like "dbContext.function()". I don't want to make reference to any table, once I don't need the table data, just the function return.

Comment: Are you able to run `_databaseContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` method?

Comment: @viveknuna, I could... but isn't it for different statements like update, delete, etc?

Comment: instead of using function you can use stored procedure and get the out parameter in place of return value

Comment: I found out a way to do that with the functions, but it someone have a better option... please, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Reading EF Core documentation I found out a way to do that as I wanted. It doesn't seem to be possible to map a function to use straight from dbcontext, but EF gives you the connection and you can use it as an ADO.NET reader. So creating the function inside the XDbContext I can use it in a simplest way.

```
public class XDbContext : DbContext
{
    //MAPPED OBJECTS
    //....
    //....


    public XDbContext(DbContextOptions<XDbContext> options)
            : base(options) { }

    public string f_MyFunction()
    {
        var fResult = "";

        var conn = this.Database.GetDbConnection();

        conn.Open();

        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            string query = "SELECT DBO.MyFunction()";

            cmd.CommandText = query;

            DbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                reader.Read();
                fResult = reader.GetString(0);
            }
        }

        return fResult ;
    }
}
```

[That's just a test, I am gonna implement the functions in a better way!]

If someone has a better option, please let me know. I would really appreciate to get to know more about EF Core possibilities into this scope.

Comment: Was this code ever tested? Is the query syntax correct?

Comment: It works, but I would not do that anymore. I'd prefer to implement the code to execute DB Functions in a repository level tho.